# OrientDB - index of one record in select results

Tags: orientdb, orientjs

Can without scripts language get record position in select resutls set?

For example, i have some `mySelect` select with results:

```
[{ ..., value: 1 }, { '@rid': '#9:1', value: 2 }, { ..., value: 3 }]
```

Any i want to get index of #9:1 some how like that (pseudo code):

```
select indexOf('#9:1') from (mySelect)
```

or

```
select indexOf(select from (mySelect) where @rid='#9:1')
```

Needed result:

`1`

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the position of a substring by querying a string (JSON) resultset as such:

```
SELECT @this.toJSON().indexOf("#9:1") FROM mySelect WHERE @rid = #9:1
```

For reference, check out the [documentation](https://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Where.html#record-attributes). I hope this helps.